# When does URL to .csv open or download file?

Tags: pandas, csv, http

I'm learning some Python pandas and the course uses https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sh7ata/e075ff35b51ebb0d2d577fbe1d19ebc9/raw/b966d02c7c26bcca60703acb1390e938a65a35cb/drinks.csv

Clicking this link **opens** the actual .csv file contents in my browser and I can read the data into pandas straight away.

However, this doesn't work for https://www.spss-tutorials.com/downloads/browsers.csv. If I click this link, Google Chrome **downloads** the file rather than show its contents.

Why is this and what can I do about it? I mean, they're both URLs for .csv files, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests` module with custom HTTP header to download it. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


url = "https://www.spss-tutorials.com/downloads/browsers.csv"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(req.text))

print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | screen_resolution | sessions | perc_new_sessions | new_users | bounce_rate | pages_session | avg_session_duration | goal_conversion_rate | goal_completions | goal_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1366x768 | 2,284 | 79.60% | 1,818 | 69.40% | 1.93 | 00:02:14 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 1 | 1920x1080 | 2,013 | 72.28% | 1,455 | 71.93% | 2.02 | 00:02:18 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 2 | 1280x1024 | 1,217 | 72.14% | 878 | 74.53% | 1.9 | 00:02:05 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 3 | 1680x1050 | 1,052 | 68.16% | 717 | 74.62% | 1.93 | 00:01:46 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 4 | 1440x900 | 921 | 77.85% | 717 | 74.05% | 1.73 | 00:01:45 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 5 | 1280x800 | 865 | 80.00% | 692 | 71.91% | 1.76 | 00:01:37 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 6 | 1600x900 | 737 | 76.39% | 563 | 72.86% | 1.8 | 00:02:02 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 7 | 1920x1200 | 441 | 64.85% | 286 | 73.92% | 1.87 | 00:01:55 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 8 | 1024x768 | 192 | 88.02% | 169 | 73.96% | 2.07 | 00:01:32 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 9 | 2560x1440 | 137 | 67.15% | 92 | 61.31% | 1.86 | 00:02:02 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 10 | 1280x720 | 134 | 82.84% | 111 | 66.42% | 2.16 | 00:01:15 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 11 | 1536x864 | 118 | 78.81% | 93 | 72.03% | 1.78 | 00:01:45 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 12 | 320x568 | 104 | 84.62% | 88 | 75.00% | 1.89 | 00:01:18 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 13 | 768x1024 | 91 | 83.52% | 76 | 67.03% | 2.66 | 00:02:11 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 14 | 1360x768 | 70 | 77.14% | 54 | 74.29% | 1.69 | 00:01:08 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 15 | 360x640 | 70 | 71.43% | 50 | 77.14% | 2.06 | 00:02:06 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 16 | 1600x1200 | 62 | 80.65% | 50 | 82.26% | 1.32 | 00:01:22 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 17 | 1344x840 | 56 | 44.64% | 25 | 53.57% | 3.11 | 00:04:39 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 18 | 320x480 | 51 | 80.39% | 41 | 72.55% | 1.61 | 00:00:55 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 19 | 1093x614 | 41 | 80.49% | 33 | 78.05% | 1.76 | 00:01:42 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 20 | 1280x768 | 38 | 60.53% | 23 | 68.42% | 2.63 | 00:02:41 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |
| 21 | 1024x600 | 35 | 94.29% | 33 | 85.71% | 1.37 | 00:01:23 | 0.00% | 0 | â‚¬0.00 |

<sup>...and so on</sup>